# Extracting variable from array for use in command on CMD

Tags: arrays, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to make a CMD batch script that constantly logs IP statistics and puts them in different .txt files, for this I have created 2 arrays, one that contains the names I wish to give to the txt files and other one that contains the ips I wish to ping.

I try to loop the elements in the arrays as names/parameters for different commands on the CMD shell, the part for the .txt names works but I can't get extracting the ip addresses from the corresponding array and passing them to the ping command to work. My code is:

```
@echo off
set Noms=(bni csc cba lpz oro pnd pts scz trj)
set Dirs=(8.8.8.8 8.8.8.4 8.8.8.4 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.4 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.4 8.8.8.8)
rem --------------------------------------------------------------
rem Builds .txts with names in list Noms pinging Addresses in Dirs
rem --------------------------------------------------------------
for %%j in %Noms% do (
set direccion = %Dirs[%%j]%
ping /n 3 %direccion% > c:\log\p0.txt
findstr "Media" c:\log\p0.txt > c:\log\p1.txt
for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%i in (c:\log\p1.txt) do @echo %%i > c:\log\p2.txt
for /f "tokens=4 delims=<equal> " %%i in (c:\log\p2.txt) do @echo %%i > c:\log\p0.txt
for /f "tokens=1 delims=m" %%i in (c:\log\p0.txt) do (set pingvar=%%i)
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b) 
For /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/:," %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a:%%b:%%c) 
set totvar=%mydate%     %mytime%    %pingvar%
echo %totvar% > c:\log\%%j.txt
)
```

I found no mistake in my code, basically I try to put the IP address from the array "Dirs" in the variable "direccion" and then passit as an argument to ping.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: That's because `%Dirs[...]%` doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, then what would the correct syntax be??

Comment: Given you have a predefined set of names and ips I think you should construct your "array" with something like `set "Dirs[bni]=8.8.8.8"`, ..., `set "Dirs[trj]=8.8.8.8"`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working either, closer inspection reveals the output from ping is "Could not find host Dirs[1]", which I guess means the script isn't passing "bni" or "trj" as index for the list or array

Answer (score 1):

You have to use enable delayed expansion. I'll show a sample code with some of your names

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "names=bni csc cba"
set "Dirs[bni]=1.1.1.1"
set "Dirs[csc]=2.2.2.2"
set "Dirs[cba]=3.3.3.3"

for %%I in (%names%) do (
   echo(Name:%%I, IP:!Dirs[%%I]!
)
```

The output for the above is:

```
Name:bni, IP:1.1.1.1
Name:csc, IP:2.2.2.2
Name:cba, IP:3.3.3.3
```

Hope it helps.